# Vertical space insertion in different contexts

Tags: line-spacing

This is my first post, I hope it's not too redundant with existing stuff. Having used Latex for a while, but always with a very utilitarian approach, I always get confused with the \vspace command, which I find somewhat counterintuitive.

In the following minimal example, I am looking for commands to manually add white vertical spaces (yes, I know it's ugly!) at the various locations indicated by the commented 'skipspace' macros.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\newlength{\addspace}
\setlength{\addspace}{0mm} % play easily on the inserted length
\begin{document}

First paragraph~: starts off with some very interesting text,
until we encounter a first equation~:
%\skipspace1{\addspace}
$$
x=5,
$$
%\skipspace2{\addspace}
after what the paragraph continues, with some even more interesting
text, and finally ends with another equation~:
$$
x=5.
$$
%\skipspace3{\addspace}

Second paragraph~: we are going to encounter a line break
(don't ask why I like to have these from time to time).\\
%\skipspace4{\addspace}
This is the same paragraph continuing after the break.
%\skipspace5{\addspace}

Third paragraph~: whatever. As far as I'm concerned, the example is over,
but multiple-line paragraphs definitely look better.
\end{document}
```

As far as my experience goes, locations "1" and "5" are well handled by \vspace, whereas locations "2", "3" and "4" require some tweaking every time (because \vspace does not work intuitively at the beginning of a new line). For the momentt, I use an ugly hack based on a line with a single white space in it:

For cases 2 and 4, the following works :

```
\ \vspace{\addspace}\\[-\baselineskip]
```

For case 3, the following works :

```
\ \vspace{\addspace}\\[-2\baselineskip]
```

Now my question is : is there a general macro (prettier than my hack) that will jointly take care of cases "2", "3, and "4" ? Or even better (just dreaming), is there a general macro that could directly handle all 5 cases ?

Thanks in advance for your time and explanations,

Howard

EDIT : You can find my self-answer further down, thanks to the reply of David Carlisle

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You'd get better results by not using `$$` and acting (locally) on `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` (or the “short” variants thereof). Can you better explain what's your aim?

Comment: Thanks for the response. My aim is to have a "simple toolbox" for locally tweaking vertical spacing between *any* two elements of content (mostly text, graphics and equations). The main application would be when I use beamer, where I somehow find that the visually-optimal spacing is always better achieved manually.

Answer (score 3):

If `\vspace` is used in vertical mode the space is added at that point. If it is added in horizontal mode it is deferred until the paragraph is broken into lines and then the space is added after the line that contained the node carrying the deferred space.

The behaviour in horizontal mode is sort of justifiable but rarely wanted so the simple rule is always leave a blank line before `\vspace`.

The other rule to note is that you should never leave a blank line before display math (which should not be marked with `$$` in latex, but same applies to `\[`).

---

```
\ \vspace{\addspace}\\[-2\baselineskip]
```

is a very bizarre construct:  if used in vertical mode, it will start a paragraph with a paragraph indentation, then a forced word space from `\` then a forced break from `\\` If a blank line follows the line after the break will be empty and generate a underfull hbox warning. Then the paragraph will end so
the `\addspace` will be added after the first white line.  So you will generate two white hboxes which are not discarded at a pagebreak and have `\addspace - 2\baselineskip` space in between. This will look similar to a space of `\addspace` but the interaction with text above and below will be different and the behaviour at a page break will be completely wrong, allowing a page break between the two white lines and producing anomalous white line at the top of the next page.

Comment: David, thanks for the explanations. I did not know there was a difference between $$ and \\[, and I somehow got used to the former. As for the hack I use in "Case 3", although your detailed explanation is above my head, even *I* could tell that it's damn ugly ^^ 
I just did not find another way of achieving the desired behavior : have everything under the equation translated by an amount of \addspace.

Comment: @HowieR what is your real use case? You should almost never have explicit spacing within the document. Sometimes it is unavoidable, but only sometimes, and only for final publication adjustments. Ah in a comment above you said beamer, OK in a presentation where all page breaking is anyway manual, you may want finer manual control.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David Carlisle's response, I figured that "Case 3" (inserting space between an equation and the following paragraph) is also easily done with \vspace, except you have to insert it between two blank lines. So if I summarize my current solution, it goes~:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\newlength{\addspace}
\setlength{\addspace}{0mm} % play easily on the inserted length

\newcommand{\myvspace}[1]{\ \vspace{#1}\\[-baselineskip]} % home-made ugly macro

\begin{document}

First paragraph~: starts off with some very interesting text,
until we encounter a first equation~:
\vspace{\addspace} % CASE 1
\[
x=5,
\]
\myvspace{\addspace} % CASE 2
after what the paragraph continues, with some even more interesting
text, and finally ends with another equation~:
\[
x=5.
\]

\vspace{\addspace} % CASE 3... blank lines above and below are important to enter vertical mode

Second paragraph~: we are going to encounter a line break
(don't ask why I like to have these from time to time).\\
\myvspace{\addspace} % CASE 4
This is the same paragraph continuing after the break.

\vspace{\addspace} % CASE 5

Third paragraph~: whatever.
\end{document}
```

So it seems that I can do all I want with \vspace (for cases 1,3,5) and my ugly home-made macro \myvspace (for cases 2 and 4)... and that's more or less ok. Thanks to all, and especially David for pointing me at the difference between horizontal and vertical mode.

Howard